# Filling an ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> with content of XML using dom4j

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, arraylist, dom4j

I'm having some trouble filling my `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` can you help me?

I have the following XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<simulation>
  <member id="House">
    <id>1</id>
    <agent_name>1</agent_name>
    <type>1</type>
    <max_usage>1</max_usage>
    <min_usage>1</min_usage>
    <average_usage>1</average_usage>
  </member>
  <member id="CSP">
    <id>2</id>
    <agent_name>2</agent_name>
    <type>2</type>
  </member>
  <member id="VPP">
    <id>3</id>
    <agent_name>3</agent_name>
    <type>3</type>
  </member>
</simulation>
```

And my code:

```
    public static void readSimulation(){
        Element root = doc.getRootElement();
        DefaultListModel tempList = new DefaultListModel();
        ArrayList<String> tempAL = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> strAL = new ArrayList<>();
        Element innerElement = null;
        for ( Iterator i = root.elementIterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            Element element = (Element) i.next();
            tempList.addElement(element.attributeValue("id")); 
            for ( Iterator j = element.elementIterator(); j.hasNext(); ) {
                innerElement = (Element) j.next();
                tempAL.add(innerElement.getTextTrim().toString()); 

            }
              strAL.add(tempAL);         
        }
```

I need the following result:

```
[[1,1,1,1,1] [2,2,2] [3,3,3]]
```

But I don't know why, I'm getting something like this:

```
[[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3] [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3] [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you should clear `tempAL` list in each iteration of for-loop. Now you are adding to the same array list.